# Ember partial onload

Tags: ember.js, onload, partial

I'm trying to draw a timeline when the timeline route is opened. Currently have  and it partially works, i.e. if you refresh the timeline page, but navigating to timeline page will not draw timeline. I was wondering if it is possible to do {{partial onload="drawTimeline}} or something along those lines.

I've also tried making a handlebars helper {{drawTimeline}} and calling that when partial is loaded, but it is getting an undefined value.

EDIT:
kingpin2k's fix worked for me. This is what I did:

HTML:

```
{{#view Blocks.Timeline}}
  <div id="mytimeline"></div>
{{/view}}
```

JS:

```
Blocks.Timeline = Em.View.extend({
didInsertElement : function(){
   drawVisualization();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is drawTimeline a function on the controller of the current route?

If so, create an associated view and hook up to the didInsertElement and run the function there.

```
App.SomethingView = Em.View.extend({
  didInsertElement : function(){
   // do it here
  }
});
```